# Can't connect to Samba file share, user/password null in Samba logs?

Tags: samba, smb

I've got a FreeNAS setup using Samba 4.6.x running WINS, and just noticed something odd. I can probably work around it but I'd like to understand what I'm seeing.

Call the Samba server SVR and it has a user defined 'Jane' with a password, and the workgroup is WORKGROUP.  On the Windows 8.1 client I have in Credential Manager an entry with server "SVR", user "WORKGROUP\Jane" and the password, and WINS hard-set to the server's IP (checked via ipconfig/all).   I've also tried variations on credentials such as user: svr\Jane, svr\jane, SVR/Jane, etc etc.  Wireshark shows clearly the firewall isn't impeding traffic. But SMB's not working properly or showing a connection in Windows.

When I look at the logs the basic issue is obvious - the user or user domain (or both) is null [ ] and gets rejected because its an unknown user.  I have smb.conf set to reject unknown users and not to allow them as guest sessions, so this is desired behaviour for the data, the issue seems to be that (according to nmbd/smbd logs) the data supplied during negotiation isn't as expected.

I don't think the issue is server-side config. I can see on both client-side wireshark and packet capture on the network switch that the SMB packet from the client has **user= domain = (empty string)**, and in the server-side smbd log the incoming client request has **[ ] / [ ] @ CLIENT_MACHINE_NAME**, and later on, **"check_ntlm_password: Authentication for user [ ] -> [ ] failed with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER"** and **"sam authentication for user [ ] failed."**.  I'm also sure it's not related to the user/password defined on Samba, because "Jane/Jane" exists in smb.conf and is found by `pdbedit -L Jane/Jane/JANE`, and the error is unknown user, not bad password/not authorised.

What might be going on and why isn't it getting the correct credentials supplied by Windows, and receiving (or reporting) null instead?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the global section of your `smb.conf`? Are you sure the user is in the Samba user database (`pdbedit -L`)?

Comment: Deleted my comment and added info (and other info) to OP. Haven't added smb.conf (yet) as it just doesn't seem there is any issue server-side, see OP updated info.